# XeTeX (I think) problem with Mac OS X.9

Tags: xetex, context, mactex

Just upgraded to Mac OS X.9 Maverick and `XeTeX` (at least us used from `TexWorks`, which is all I've tried) now seems to be broken though it was working before. Error message when I try to typeset with `ConTeXt/XeTeX`:

> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in
>   'require':
>   /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/scripts/context/ruby/base/switch.rb:501:
>   invalid multibyte escape: /\xFF/ (SyntaxError)    from
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in
>   'require'     from
>   /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/scripts/context/ruby/texexec.rb:11:in
>   `'

Anyone else having this? Any ideas?  (I'm relatively new to both TeX and Macs, as well as this site, so apologies if this is inappropriate, poorly asked or a stupid question. :) )

**Edit:** The problem occurs even on minimal files with both ConTeXt/XeTeX and ConTeXt/pdfTeX but not with ConTeXt/LuaTeX. Complete reinstallation of MacTeX has not helped.

Comment: I am able to typeset a simple ConTeXt document with XeConTeXt using TeXWorks on OS 10.9. So there is not a problem specifically with that combination.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem. The problem is the fact that the multibyte escape '/\xFF/' is not allowed in the standard character encoding. (UTF-8?)

So to solve this problem, you have to change the file named in the error message:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/scripts/context/ruby/base/switch.rb
```

I used the terminal:

```
sudo nano -c /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/scripts/context/ruby/base/switch.rb
```

Then go to line 501 (the -c makes sure you can see the line-numbers) and change the /\xFF/ to /\x01/. In my case it did the trick!

You can see these /\xFF/'s everywhere in the ruby-codes. But context doesn't seem to need them so they don't give an error message.

Comment: By the looks of it, it seems to relate to arguments parsing (for which there are gems, hmm). I think it's because OSX went from ruby-1.8 straight to 2, where the whole UTF-8 handling has been revamped. The script does include a magic encoding line, but I guess the regexp's would need that specification, too. Anyway, long story short, even though your change makes it work, I don't think it's a very clean way.

Answer (score 1):

See (a duplicate) [Unable to run ConTeXt (pdfTeX) after upgrading to Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142054/unable-to-run-context-pdftex-after-upgrading-to-mac-os-x-10-9-mavericks).

If you upgrade MacTeX tomorrow it should apply the same patch as mentioned by Denni (and two other patches) and it should start working.