# Unable to run ConTeXt (pdfTeX) after upgrading to Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks

Tags: context

I recently upgraded to Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks) and tried to run a old ConTeXt document using  TeXWorks. I got the following error:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/rbconfig.rb:212: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/scripts/context/ruby/base/switch.rb:501: invalid multibyte escape: /\xFF/ (SyntaxError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/scripts/context/ruby/texexec.rb:11:in `<main>'
```

I had earlier loaded MacTeX 2012. I got the same error as above. So I thought may be it has to do with my TeX installation. I removed MacTeX 2012 and installed MacTeX 2013. But ended up with the same problem (error message as above).

I am kind of lost. I am new to Mac and was enjoying the TeX/LaTeX/ConTeXt experience.

Would appreciate help.

Comment: You need to install XCode and update it, I think, and install the command line tools.

Answer (score 1):

This is an incompatibility with ruby 2.0 that has recently been fixed by Hans. See ["Clean Machine, MacTeX 2013 installed, ConTeXt problem"](http://www.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2013/075016.html) on the ConTeXt mailing list.

I [committed the patch](http://tug.org/svn/texlive?view=revision&revision=32605) to TeX Live. If you upgrade the packages on MacTeX 2013 tomorrow (once your CTAN mirror catches up) or if you apply the patch yourself, it should work.