# Error message when compiling ConTeXt document from Emacs

Tags: context, emacs, auctex

The command

```
texexec --once --texutil --engine=xetex --interface=en --nonstop tmp.tex'
```

gives the following error message when called from Emacs, but not when called from Terminal:

`` /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in require': /opt/local/share/texmf-local/scripts/context/ruby/base/switch.rb:501: invalid multibyte escape: /\xFF/ (SyntaxError)
    from         /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:inrequire'
    from /opt/local/share/texmf-local/scripts/context/ruby/texexec.rb:11:in `' ``

The offending piece of code is

```
value.gsub(/\xFF/o, ' ')
```

At this point, I'll be grateful for everything from what to do to make the code run from Emacs, to a patch to the code.

`PATH`, `LANG`, `LC`, and `LC_ALL` are the same in both Emacs and Terminal.

Comment: How are you running this command? From one of the many Emacs shells? Via `M-!`? `M-x compile` (which is likely what I'd suggest)?

Comment: texexec is a shell command that compiles ConTeXt documents.

ConTeXt is an exension of TeX.

I would prefer to call this command from auc-tex, which is an Emacs package for TeX/LaTeX/ConTeXt editing.

It would be silly to call it from M-x compile. 
Calling it from M-! gives the same error message as above. Again, this works fine if called from the Terminal app.

Comment: I am familiar with both ConTeXt and `texexec`. I don't see what is silly about running this command via `M-x compile`; you're compiling something. In any case, if it doesn't work via `M-x compile` the question isn't relevant. Have you tried?

Comment: M-x compile presupposes a Makefile. But by all means, I created a Makefile, did M-x compile, and got the same error message as before.

Comment: `M-x compile` works without a `Makefile`; you simply need to feed it the command you want to run. Seems like a dead end anyway.

Comment: Well … this indicates that it's probably not a file encoding issue. This is weird.

Comment: I edited line 501 of switch.rb from \xFF to \0xFF and it worked. A bug report has been filed.

Comment: Please, write your solution as answer and accept it. This will mark the problem as solved in the overview.

Comment: OK.

Apparently, Ruby 2.0 breaks some of ConTeXt's scripts.

Answer (score 2):

See [Unable to run ConTeXt (pdfTeX) after upgrading to Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142054/unable-to-run-context-pdftex-after-upgrading-to-mac-os-x-10-9-mavericks).  The problem has been fixed in ConTeXt version 2013.10.20 07:09 already. I committed the patch also to TeX Live (but I'm not sure where your TeX distribution comes from).

Comment: Should we dupe, then?

Comment: I leave the decision up to you, the experienced ones. All three questions point to the same problem and fall into the category of "bug reports" that will remain relevant until everyone upgrades to a patched TL 2013 or TL 2014. (It is not clear to me which question could be treated as a duplicate of which.)

Comment: There is also (an even older) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140629/xetex-i-think-problem-with-mac-os-x-9

Comment: The sentence "This question has been asked before and already has an answer" isn't quite accurate though. The last link seems to be the first question in chronological order.

Comment: We have the occasional 'reverse dupe': sometimes  later question just turns out to be better than an earlier one.

Answer (score 0):

I edited line 501 of switch.rb from \xFF to \0xFF and it worked. A bug report has been filed.